# Can an htm file be imported into Trimble's Data Dictionary Editor?

Tags: gps, import, trimble

We've received several data dictionary files from other entities and they all are in *.htm format. We were hoping to not reinvent the wheel, as these are massive data dictionaries.

Does anyone know if there is any way to import these files into Trimble's Pathfinder Office data dictionary editor?

This is from more than one entity, so it made me wonder if there's something I'm missing or didn't know about htm files and data dictionary files.

Here's a snippet of the htm file, I cut out several < dd> and < dt>:

```
<dt><em>Attribute_Label:</em>  PostSystem</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Definition:</em>  Sign post system.</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Definition_Source:</em>  GIS/BCPWD</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Domain_Values:</em>  
<dl>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain:</em>  
<dd>
<dl>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value:</em>  Other</dt>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value_Definition:</em>  Other</dt>
</dd>
<dt><em>Attribute_Domain_Values:</em>  
<dl>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain:</em>  
<dd>
<dl>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value:</em>  Round</dt>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value_Definition:</em>  Round</dt>
</dd>
<dt><em>Attribute_Domain_Values:</em>  
<dl>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain:</em>  
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value:</em>  Telespar</dt>
<dt><em>Enumerated_Domain_Value_Definition:</em>  Telespar</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute:</em>  
<dl>
<dt><em>Attribute_Label:</em>  PostSupport</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Definition:</em>  Sign post support.</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Definition_Source:</em>  GIS/BCPWD</dt>
<dt><em>Attribute_Domain_Values:</em>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I worked with a trimble dictionary.
It should be too difficult to parse out the portions you need.
I would start with a small export from trimble to a text file and compare that to your htm (hwhich is just a glorified text file).
I do remember that the dictionary editor has some options for input and output.